# Upload Pictures - multipart/form-data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload pictures to Facebook, so I can use them in some sponsored posts.

The pictures are in my computer, so I need to upload them first to Facebook. I read that I need to upload them using multipart/form-data, but I don't know nothing related to it. If I create this this multipart/form-data, wouldn't I need to create a form and interact with it (click in the upload button, choose the picture and submit).

Is there a way to do it automatically? How can I create this multipart/form-data and use it inside my PHP without having to click in the submit button? Just get the result of it and use it to create my post, and also upload more than 1 picture at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?
$filename='image.png';
$link='http://domain.com/somepage';
$post=array('file'=>'@'.$filename);
$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17",
"Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
"Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1"));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);  
$pagetext=curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

`image.png` is a example name of image, that place in root directory.

This script send file `image.png` to the page `http://domain.com/somepage` by `POST` request.

Another POST variables may be add to `$post` array. `@` is need to send file.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. Sorry for my ignorance, but is this script using the multipart/form-data? Because I need to use this type of upload to use pictures from my computer in Facebook post.s

Comment: `multipart/form-data` header add automatically by `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);` because $post is array. For more information visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php